# "How aware are managers of ..." vs "How managers are aware of ...?" Any difference in Asking and Replying?

Tags: questions, responses

Asking:

A1

> How **aware** are managers of employee attitudes and behaviours?

A2

> How managers are **aware** of employee attitudes and behaviours?

Replying:

R1

> Managers are **very well aware** of employee attitudes and behaviours

R2

> Managers are **quite unaware** of employee attitudes and behaviours

R3

> Managers are **blissfully unaware** of employee attitudes and behaviours

R4

> Managers are **totally unaware** of employee attitudes and behaviours

I have some questions.

> First, do both A1 and A2 ask the degree of awareness?
>
> Second, do both A1 and A2 have the same meaning?
>
> Third, is there any differece in meaning or usage between A1 and A 2?
>
> Fourth, do these R1, R2, R3 and R4 match A1 or A2?

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A2 is not a question.

It is grammatical as a subordinate clause (which could, for example, be the subject or object of a verb) but it is not grammatical as a sentence on its own.

Questions in English require the verb (or auxiliary, but that's not relevant here) to precede the subject.

All the answers match A1.

**Edit**: it's occurred to me that you may be thinking of A3:

> How are managers aware of employee attitudes and behaviours?

This is grammatical, but has a quite different meaning. When *how* modifies an adjective or adverb (as in "how aware") it means "how much?" But when it modifies a predicate, as in A3, it cannot usually have this meaning, so it must have its normal meaning "in what way?" So A3 is asking about the means by which managers become aware of the attitudes or behaviours.

Comment: I kind of realise that A2 could be as a subordinate clause. For example, We need to investigate how managers are aware of employee attitudes and behaviours. A3 is a quite good example to clear my mind.

Answer (score 3):

R1, R2, R3 and R4 all can be answers to A1.

However, A1 and A2 do not have the *same meaning*.

In **A1 the emphasis is on the managers' knowledge** about employee attitudes and behaviours but in **A2 the emphasis is on the method by which managers' know** about employee attitudes and behaviours.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. A3 does emphasize on the means by which managers increase awareness of the attitudes or behavious in your explanation.